# Characterization of $T+T^*\geq 0$, for $T$ a bounded operator on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

(This is Exercise 3.2.1 in Pedersen's book *Analysis Now*.) Let $T$ be a bounded operator on a complex Hilbert space $H$. I want to prove that $T+T^*\geq 0$ if and only if $T+I$ is invertible in $\mathcal{B}(H)$ with $\|(T-I)(T+I)^{-1}\|\leq 1$.

There is a hint, namely to prove that $T+T^*\geq 0$ if and only if $\|(T+I)x\|\geq\|x\|$ and $\|(T+I)x\|\geq\|(T-I)x\|$.

I can prove $\Rightarrow$ of the hint, and I can use this to prove the conclusion of the original statement. I can also show that $\|(T-I)(T+I)^{-1}\|\leq 1$ implies $\|(T+I)x\|\geq\|(T-I)x\|$, but I am having trouble with the rest.

That is, I'm trying to show that

(1) if $T+I$ invertible with $\|(T-I)(T+I)^{-1}\|\leq 1$, then $\|(T+I)x\|\geq\|x\|$, and

(2) if $\|(T+I)x\|\geq\|x\|$ and $\|(T+I)x\|\geq\|(T-I)x\|$, then $T+T^*\geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part a) the proof by contradiction: suppose that $(I+T)x=y$ and $\|y\|<\|x\|.$
Then, $\|(T-I)(I+T)^{-1}y\|=\|(T-I)x\|=\|y-2x\|\ge 2\|x\|-\|y\|>\|y\|,$ which contradicts to our norm condition. For the second part,
suppose that $Tx=y.$ The condition $\|(I+T)x\|\ge \|x\|$ implies $(x+y,x+y)\ge (x,x)$ or $\|y\|^2+(x,y)+(y,x)\ge 0.$ The second condition is equivalent to $(x+y,x+y)\ge (y-x,y-x)$ or $(x,y)+(y,x)\ge 0.$ The only thing left is to check what that $T+T^*$ is equivalent to $((T+T^*)x,x)\ge 0$ or $(y,x)+(x,y)\ge 0.$

Comment: It looks like what I labeled as (1) is actually unnecessary; once you know that $\|(T+I)x\|\geq\|(T-I)x\|$, you have that $(Tx,Tx)+(Tx,x)+(x,Tx)+(x,x)\geq(Tx,Tx)-(Tx,x)-(x,Tx)+(x,x)$, and so, $((T+T^*)x,x)=(Tx,x)+(x,Tx)\geq 0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yep, it is correct.